# How can I switch spaces on OS X without the keyboard?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-spaces, expose

**I want to know if there is a way I can switch spaces on OS X without using `control+1` or `control+(arrow key)`.**

For some reason this is locking up my keyboard. It probably has to do with another program I'm running, possibly LiteSwitch. This started happening when I updated to 10.6.8.

I was actually using applescript to switch spaces - so I don't mind using some utility or script to switch spaces. Is there something like a helper app that could do this?

I looked at the built in options for Quicksilver and Better Touch Tool, but I didn't see any options to assign space switching to them.

**Edit:**

I know I can set the a mouse action, or a script, to pull up all the spaces and then click one, but I am curious to know how to switch *directly* to a specifc space without using the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable "Show Spaces in menu bar" in System Preferences → Exposé and Spaces. You'll gain a utility in the menu bar that lets you switch directly to a space.

[image: picture of Spaces menu bar utility]

Answer (score 2):

You can use your mouse if you [set Spaces to a hot corner](http://www.usingmac.com/2008/3/27/display-hot-corners):

1. Go to **Apple** > **System Preferences**.
2. You have two options here:

   1. Enter Desktop & Screen Saver Preferences Pane.
      Click on the button labelled "Hot Corners".
   2. Enter Expose and Spaces Preferences.
3. Here, you can set the hot corners; so, you could set one corner to Spaces.
4. You might also want to avoid accidental triggering by adding a modifier there.

[image]

Comment: I should have written "how can I switch *directly* to a space" without the keyboard. Is that possible?